# Finding if point is inside geometry

Tags: c++, stl, geometry, polygon, point

I am writing a code that requires finding if a point is inside a specific geometry. The geometry may an n sided polygon (not necessarily convex) in 2 Dimensions or an STL geometry in 3 dimensions. I can actually write a search code using some algorithms available. But I am looking for a software library that can serve such purposes. It can be part of a bigger library. Any suggestion towards any such libraries or codes freely available would do. Thank You.

Comment: Did you look at http://cgal.org?

Answer (score 14):

How about [Wykobi](https://github.com/ArashPartow/wykobi)

> Wykobi is an extremly efficient, robust and simple to use C++ 2D/3D
>   oriented computational geometry library.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out these:

http://www.cgal.org/

http://clb.demon.fi/MathGeoLib/nightly/

http://pointclouds.org/

http://www.geometrictools.com/

http://pointclouds.org/

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/index.html