# Check if point is inside a custom mesh geometry

Tags: three.js

What would be the easiest way to check if a point is inside a custom (irregular) mesh geometry?

Comment: Three dimensions (three.js)... and in JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your mesh is close-up. You can use the THREE.js built-in ray-caster. Sample code is as

```js
const point = new THREE.Vector3(2,2,2) // Your point
const geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 5, 5, 5 )
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } )
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material )
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster()
raycaster.set(point, new THREE.Vector3(1,1,1))
const intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(mesh)
if( intersects.length %2 === 1) { // Points is in objet
   console.log(`Point is in object`)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/89/three.js"></script>
```

Comment: There are 2 important things to know if using this approach: 1. Make sure your object's material.side property is set to DoubleSide or BackSide, otherwise the raycaster won't return any intersects coming from inside the object.
2. If the ray intersects exactly at an edge of multiple faces, multiple intersects will be returned. Before checking intersects % 2 === 1, you should filter out intersects that share the same .point as another intersect using .point.equals

Answer (score 3):

Just raycast once from the point to any direction, then check the intersects num, if is odd, the point is in the geometry, here is the [demo](https://github.com/gonnavis/whether_point_in_3d_model)

Comment: CAREFUL! This only works if your material is double-sided, which it usually isn't due to backface culling.

Answer (score 2):

This is a computational geometry problem. You can look at [Finding if point is inside geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631163/). Since your geometry is irregular the problem is much harder.

But if precision is not too important you can check if the point is inside the bounding box of the geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to check it using the dot product of ray direction and face normal

tested on three.js (r103)

```js
const point = new THREE.Vector3(2, 2, 2) // Your point
const direction = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1);
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 5)
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster()

raycaster.set(point, direction)
const intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(mesh);

if (intersects.length && direction.dot(intersects[0].face.normal) > 0) {
  console.log(`Point is in object`);
} else {
  console.log(`Point is out of object`);
}
```

In rare cases you can get even number of interections with point located inside the mesh

(try `point = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0)`, that should give 4 intersections)