# Three js special event listener

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, virtual-reality

I'm just starting out with Three js and I'm looking for a special event listener which I can't find nothing about on the internet.

So I'm asking you if it's possible to trigger an action when the viewer in first person enters an object.
Any suggestion is well accepted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a special event listener which I can't find nothing about on the internet.

Such an event listener does not exist in `three.js`. It seems you are looking for: [Check if point is inside a custom mesh geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361327/check-if-point-is-inside-a-custom-mesh-geometry)